# GCE VM shuts down after having Shield VM enabled and will not boot

Tags: google-compute-engine

We have recently enabled Shield VM on a node. The node restarted fine afterwards, however has since shut down and won't boot. We see any boot sequence in the logs as shutting down due to shield VM:

```
{
 insertId: "3"  
 jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent"   
  bootCounter: "4"   
  shutdownEvent: {
  }
 }
 logName: "projects/project_name/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fshielded_vm_integrity"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2021-03-26T09:30:41.307564027Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {…}   
  type: "gce_instance"   
 }
 severity: "NOTICE"  
 timestamp: "2021-03-26T09:30:39.300465584Z"  
}
```

However there appears no integrity violation. We have tried disabling Shield VM but still encounter the error. The event prior to shutdown is a late boot event:

```
insertId: "2"
jsonPayload: {
lateBootReportEvent: {
actualMeasurements: [4]
policyEvaluationPassed: true
```

Is there any way to bypass the Shield VM checks embedded in the boot sequence to get the node up?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to disable all the shielded-vm tags applied to the node, including the integrity-monitoring, through the Cloud Shell or the Shielded VM tab of the VM, then try to boot the node again. You can make use of the command:

```
gcloud beta compute instances update YOUR_NODE_NAME --no-shielded-integrity-monitoring --no-shielded-secure-boot] --no-shielded-vtpm
```

You can find more info about the command and the tags [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/update).

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion @alejopp. We were unable to boot the device with all Shield VM flags disabled, so rebuilt the node in the end - was a Production environment...

Comment: @NickBrennan Could you please post the solution/workaround you found as an answer? This will help others in the community who are facing similar problems.